# ASP .NET - Using RequiredFieldValidator when page has two listviews?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with two Listviews (with two different data sources).  I have added **RequiredFieldValidator** controls to each of the **InsertItemTemplate** controls.

The first problem is that once all the validators were added they started requiring that both Listviews be populated before inserting.  To fix this I tried to add different validation groups to the listviews but now the field validators don't work!

How do I get the Validators to work independently based on the Listview they are attached to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure both the ListViews ***and*** their respective RequiredFieldValidators have matching ValidationGroups.

Comment: Thanks - Needed to add it to the Insert button.

<asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" ValidationGroup="details" />

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`ValidationGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) attribute.  Set the attribute to a different value for each relevant control in each `ListView`.  For example, when a button is clicked with a `ValidationGroup` set, only the validators with a matching `ValidationGroup` are considered.